# How to hide button from context menu on SP view

Tags: list-view, ribbon

I have a SharePoint view, and I want to hide "Share with" button when click to context menu of this view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly just to warn you that trying to hide the "Share with" option in SharePoint 2013 can be a bit like playing 'whack-a-mole'.

The following CSS will hide this option on the context menu and also the ribbon bar (which was probably going to be your next question:-)).  We normally have this in a CSS file that's loaded by a custom master page used in all sites.

```
/* Hiding share: */
/* The "Shared with" context menu item opens a dialog with some options to share. */
/* The following classes can be used to hide these options */
.js-sharing-fullListDialogCommandsLeft {
}
.js-sharing-fullListDialogCommandInvite {
    display: none!important;
}
.js-sharing-fullListDialogCommandEmail {
    display: none!important;
}
.js-sharing-fullListDialogCommandAdvanced {
}
/* Hide the "Share" ribbon button */
#Ribbon\.Documents\.Share\.ShareItem-Large {
    display: none;
}
/* End Hide share */
```

Comment: It can not hide "Share with" button on context menu

Comment: I'd forgotten the approach we'd ended up using but you're right it doesn't completely hide it but what it does do is remove the Invite/Email options from the dialog that's then displayed so users can't then use this option.  This was to allow administrators/owners to still have the option to go to the advanced settings and set permissions (just like SharePoint 2010).  Normal users (Read/Contribute) don't see this option as it's security trimmed.  If you did want to hide the advanced option for all users then add a display: none to .js-sharing-fullListDialogCommandAdvanced